# No overload for 'subbut_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have bit of code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Globalization; 

namespace DEMO
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void brwbut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;                         
            }
        }

        private void subbut_Click(string fileName, string tableName)
        {
            string connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO\"";
            string fieldstring  = "(ID int, Field1 char(255),Field2 char(255))";

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"CREATE TABLE [{0}] {1}", tableName, fieldstring);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        public void InsertRow(String fileName, String tableName, string data)
        {
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\"";
            string headers = "ID,Field1,Field2";

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"INSERT INTO [{0}$] ({1}) values({2})", tableName, headers, data);
                    //txtQuery.Text = cmd.CommandText;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    InsertRow("C:\\path\\to\\file\\Test File.xls", "ListingDetails",
                        "'" + i.ToString() + "','test" + (i + 2).ToString() + "','test" + (i + 5).ToString() + "'");
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I keep getting an annoying error

> No overload for 'subbut_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

that I don't know how to approach. I have been searching online and trouble shooting for a while and have not found any answers. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you think those parameters are?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your handler's parameters don't match the event.

`Click` is defined as a `System.EventHandler`, which takes `object sender, EventArgs e`.

Comment: then how can i use object for "string fileName, string tableName"

Answer (score 0):

The `.Click` event expects to be wired to a `System.EventHandler`. The [`EventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) is a `delegate` that has a signature of:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(
    object sender,
    EventArgs e
)
```

Change this

```
private void subbut_Click(string fileName, string tableName)
```

to this

```
private void subbut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

If the `string` values you're looking for are needed within this method, you'll need to get them another way. Are these values exposed on the UI as a `TextBox`, if so this is simple?

```
private void subbut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // "textBox1" contains the text value for the filename
    string fileName = textBox1.Text;

    // This is the only missing piece that you need now. 
    // You are not going to get the value for the table name from the click event.
    // Instead you need to get it from the user input, i.e.; a textbox control.
    string tableName = tableTextBox.Text;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: for fileName working fine but i cant define for tableName

Comment: still i am facing same problem

Comment: What is invoking that method?

Comment: Here i have used one input text box and upload button and submit button. Input text box used for to get input file from user

Comment: private void subbut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = fileName;
            string tableName = tableName;
            string connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO\"";
            string fieldstring  = "(ID int, Field1 char(255),Field2 char(255))";